# Connect one view to another in seperate NIBs using Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uiwindow, iboutlet

I have a custom UIWindow class that has an IBOutlet

```
@interface MyWindow
    IBOutlet UIView * someView;
    id <MyWindowDelegate> delegate; 
    // to inform a controller something happened to view
@end

@interface MyControllerThatContainsSomeView
    IBOutlet UIWebView * theConcreteView;
@end
```

I have changed my Window in MainWindow.xib to MyWindow. Is there a way, through interface builder, in which I can reference **someView** from *MyControllerThatContainsSomeView.xib*

so, MainWindow.MyWindow.someView -> MyControllerThatContainsSomeView.theConcreteView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to it in a binding path but that's about it. Usually when you find that you need to refer from one view to another, it's time to rethink your design. Views should refer instead to model objects which provide data to the views.

Comment: how do i set a binding path. I ended up setting the MyWindow properties in code.

Comment: Oops sorry, I was thinking of Mac OS X - bindings (Cocoa Bindings) aren't available in iOS.